# How to stop form value resetting when using ProtectedRoutes in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have antd `Form` Component in my project. And that component is protected by `ProtectedRoute` that I created.

```
//ProtectedRoute 
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={({ location }) =>
          auth.isAuthenticated ? (
            <Component {...rest} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/account/login",
                state: { from: location },
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );


//Route
return (
   <Router>
      <Switch>
          <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={CaseSearchPage} />
           //I have another set of routes here
      </Switch>
   </Router>
);
```

But in the `CaseSearchPage` component, when I switch the language, the form data get reset. When I use `Route` instead `ProtectedRoute`, this works as expected. Is there any way to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

Since I'm using protected routes, it's re-rendering the whole component. So even the state values get cleared. To fix this, I changed the above code a bit.

```
//New protected route
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
   <Route
      render={({ location }) => (
        <Redirect
           to={{
              pathname: "/account/login",
              state: { from: location },
           }}
         />
      )}
   />
);


//new Route
return (
   <Router>
      <Switch>
         <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            component={auth.isAuthenticated ? CaseSearchPage : ProtectedRoute}
         />         
      </Switch>
   </Router>
);
```

Instead of checking `auth.isAuthenticated` inside `ProtectedRoute`, I'm checking it now in `Route`. The only thing in `ProtectedRoute` is the `Redirect` Route.